# sed multibyte unicode substitution problem

Tags: sed, unicode

I need to replace unicode characters only on specific lines of a file.  I started with:

```
#sed -r -e "/             '#text'/ s/[ɛ̀ɛ́]/ɛ/g; s/[òó]/o/g; s/[ɔ́ɔ̀]/ɔ/g " $filename
```

but was getting some strange results as per below:

```
echo zɔ̀nzɔn | sed -r -e "s/[ɛ̀ɛ́]/ɛ/g; s/[òó]/o/g; s/[ɔ́ɔ̀]/ɔ/g "                                                                                      
echo zɔ̀nzɔn | sed -r -e "s/[ɔ́ɔ̀]/ɔ/g "                                                                                                              
echo zɔ̀nzɔn | sed -r -e "y/ɔ̀/ɔ/"                                                                                                                   
echo zɔ̀nzɔn | sed -r -e 's/\x254\x300/ɔ/g '                                                                                                        
echo zɔ̀nzɔn | sed -r -e 's/\x0254\x0300/ɔ/g '                                                                                                      
echo zɔ̀nzɔn | sed -r -e 's/\u0596\u768/ɔ/g '
```

which outputs:

```
zɔɛnzɔn
zɔɔnzɔn
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: strings for `y' command are different lengths
zɔ̀nzɔn
zɔ̀nzɔn
zɔ̀nzɔn
```

The desired output is: zɔnzɔn

The first replacement inserts a ɔɛ even though there is no form of ɛ in the text; the second line is giving me two ɔɔ, (maybe because of some issue with multibyte), and the /y is complaining I assume that the multibyte is being replaced by a single character.

I am using a UTF-8 locale.   Is gnu sed just not capable here?   Thanks!!

Comment: `len('zɔ̀nzɔn')` returns `7` as there is `̀` (U+0300,  *Combining Grave Accent*) and your regex contains ```[ɛ̀ɛ́]``` (any of - `ɛ` (U+025B,  *Latin Small Letter Open E*)
- `̀` (U+0300,  *Combining Grave Accent*)
- `ɛ` (U+025B,  *Latin Small Letter Open E*)
- `́` (U+0301,  *Combining Acute Accent*) so the first replacement is right?

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: @josefz No I wouldn't say its right in the sens of what is the desired outcome.   When you want to replace ɔ̀ and the regex for ɛ̀ seems to be picking it up it doesn't seem 'right'....  I do get the issue is the multibyte characters as in the title.   But I have 44000 lines with various combos of these and more where I need to strip off the accents.   As you can see above I have tried to use hex and unicode directly for the individual combining letters/accents to no avail.

Comment: @Cyrus Added line indicating desired output zɔnzɔn.  Six sample inputs are above for example echo zɔ̀nzɔn | sed -r -e "s/[ɔ́ɔ̀]/ɔ/g " should return zɔnzɔn but returns zɔɔnzɔn (as indicated above). Its a rather simple substitution. Replace ɔ́ or ɔ̀ with ɔ. But the multibyte character seems to be causing an issue.

Comment: So further to @Josefz 's comment:  I guess that sed just can't work very well with multibyte or combining characters, especially using the [] 'or' syntax, it 'ors' without 'combining'. So probably the only solution is just to work with each character one at a time:  echo zɔ̀nzɔn | sed -r -e "s/ɛ̀/ɛ/g; s/ɛ́/ɛ/g; s/ɔ̀/ɔ/g; s/ɔ́/ɔ/g" works as expected and outputs zɔnzɔn.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to strip diacriticals off of characters, not just the case of ɔ̀? I'd use perl instead:

```bash
$ printf "%s\n" "zɔ̀nzɔn" "ɛ̀ɛ́" "òó" |
  perl -CSD -MUnicode::Normalize -pe '$_ = NFD($_); s/[\p{InDiacriticals}\p{InDiacriticalsExt}\p{InDiacriticalsForSymbols}\p{InDiacriticalsSup}]//g'
zɔnzɔn
ɛɛ
oo
```

That'll cover most cases. The idea is to make sure input is in Unicode NFD mode, and then remove codepoints in the combining diacritical mark blocks.

Answer (score 0):

It does seem that sed just can't work very well with multibyte or combining characters, especially using the [] 'or' syntax. It 'ors' without 'combining' the accent and base character. So one solution is just to work with each character one at a time:

```
echo zɔ̀nzɔn | sed -r -e "s/ɛ̀/ɛ/g; s/ɛ́/ɛ/g; s/ɔ̀/ɔ/g; s/ɔ́/ɔ/g"
```

works as expected and outputs zɔnzɔn.